# Internal server error when running php script to add watermark on images

Tags: php

Am developing new photography website in which images are uploaded frequently.... Now I want to add watermark on uploaded images before it goes to client side, I have used the following code for watermark

```
$SourceFile = "sys\img\image1.jpg";
$DestinationFile = "sys\img\image1-wm.jpg"; 
$WaterMarkText = 'Copyright sys.com';
watermarkImage ($SourceFile, $WaterMarkText, $DestinationFile);

function watermarkImage ($SourceFile, $WaterMarkText, $DestinationFile) { 
 list($width, $height) = getimagesize($SourceFile);
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($SourceFile);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height); 
$black = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0);
$font = 'arial.ttf';
$font_size = 10; 
imagettftext($image_p, $font_size, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $WaterMarkText);
if ($DestinationFile<>'') {
   imagejpeg ($image_p, $DestinationFile, 100); 
} else {
   header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
  imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
};
imagedestroy($image); 
imagedestroy($image_p); 
};
```

But it showing the following error

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your 
request.
Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything
you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

What is the mistake I have done...?

Comment: what is the error in the log file?

Comment: ==> if ($DestinationFile<>'') {  No ?

Comment: @donald123 Where to find log file?

Comment: @demenvil I cant get you..

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found an another way to add watermark to my images...

Here is the code for watermark....

```
$filename=$_REQUEST['filename'];
$imgpath="img/"; // Folder of your images in the server
$imgpath = $imgpath.$filename;
header('content-type: image/jpeg'); //HTTP header - assumes your images in the gallery are JPGs
$watermarkfile="img/watermark.png";
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng($watermarkfile);
list($watermark_width,$watermark_height) = getimagesize($watermarkfile);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgpath);
$size = getimagesize($imgpath);
$dest_x = $size[0] - $watermark_width - 15;
$dest_y = $size[1] - $watermark_height - 15;
imagecopy($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height);
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($watermark);
```

Save this code as watermark.php and then use it in the img tag as follows...

```
<img src="watermark.php?filename=image1.jpg">
```

Thats it... Working fine...